# Deploying private CA certs to debian devices

Tags: debian, openssl, ssl

We have a private certificate authority (CA) which is only used on sites in our intranet.

I can get the certificate easily:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect atlas.sim.local:8443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >atlas.crt
```

I would like my debian devices to trust this certificate authority automatically.  I have private `apt` repo, and all of my debian devices have packages from this repo installed. Therefore, I'd like this `*.crt` file to be deployed in this package.

The package will effectively do this:

```
install -Dm644 atlas.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/sim.local/atlas.crt
```

But how do I regenerate the ca-certificates once this file is deployed?  I'm looking for a file to deploy or a line I can run in `postinst`.

---

My first thought was simply:

```
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```

but `man update-ca-certificates` says:

> `update-ca-certificates` is a program that updates the directory `/etc/ssl/certs` to hold SSL certificates and generates `ca-certificates.crt` ...
>
> It  reads the file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`. Each line gives a pathname of a CA certificate under `/usr/share/ca-certificates` that should be trusted.

For this to work, I need to ensure `sim.local/atlas.crt` is in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`.  Unfortunately there is no `/etc/ca-certificates.conf.d/` which could allow me to drop-in another file with that content.

---

If I read `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`, it says:

```
# This file lists certificates that you wish to use or to ignore to be
# installed in /etc/ssl/certs.
# update-ca-certificates(8) will update /etc/ssl/certs by reading this file.
#
# This is autogenerated by dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates.
```

Therefore, I could try:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

But this causes an interactive dialog to show up which has my certificate de-selected by default.  I'd rather this was non-interactive.

---

This is my current `postinst`. but I'm not sure that it's the right solution.  Is there a right way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

case "$1" in
  configure)

    if [ -e /etc/ca-certificates.conf ] && 
      ! grep -q sim.local/atlas.crt /etc/ca-certificates.conf; then

        printf "%s\n" sim.local/atlas.crt >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf;
        /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates;
    fi
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Have you tried `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to do with noninteractive mode?

Comment: I didn't know about that one.  However calling `dpkg-reconfigure` from within `postinst` gives me:  `error: dpkg frontend lock was locked by another process...`

Comment: which process held the lock?

Comment: `dpkg -i *.deb` makes the lock.  `postinst` is called from within that, which itself calls `dpkg-reconfigure` which fails to capture the lock.  The parent process is the locking process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the easiest solution was to buy a certificate from a public CA.  It was also cheaper than spending more hours of my own time on the problem.

The common-name (CN) can have wildcards, so I bought a certificate with `CN=*.mycompany.com`, and changed the FQDN of the server from `atlas.sim.local` to `atlas.mycompany.com`.

Also, the same certificate can be used on all of our intranet services, as we are moving all machines to `*.mycompany.com`.

This works for all applications (even Firefox and Chromium with their own root CA lists), and all operating systems.

I suppose we could move the question to ServerFault, since the answer ended up being not Unix-specific.

Comment: I hope you used Let's Encrypt or similar instead of actually spending $$$ on it

Answer (score 2):

From the same man page:

> Furthermore all certificates with a .crt extension found below /usr/local/share/ca-certificates are also included as implicitly trusted.

That means you do not need to run `dpkg-reconfigure`  - simply place the `.crt` file in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, run `updates-ca-certificates` and you're done.

Comment: I thought about that.  `/usr/local/` is meant for local administration and should normally be off-limits to the package manager.  But maybe that is the easiest way.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Define _local_ :-) I'd suggest that you should be using local here as your package is site-specific, as opposed to Debian package maintainers who should not be using local.  But that is just my thoughts - I can't find anything definitive.

Comment: @Stewart Yes, per Debian policy, [it is forbidden](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#site-specific-programs) for packages to install files into `/usr/local`. This directory is reserved for local changes by the admin.

Comment: @xhienne - my thinking is/was that while it most definitely forbidden for public packages to install into `/usr/local`, is a locally developed package the same? If the admin used Ansible (for example) to push the `.crt` file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` then it would be perfectly acceptable.  Does the fact that the admin uses a local package change things?  In the end, there's no Debian Police to raid the site :-)

Comment: @garethTheRed The Debian police (`lintian`) is called at the end of package building and may output warning/errors. Of course you can probably ignore these but it's not quite neat, that would be like delivering sources that do not compile without warnings. My personal experience with Debian in general, and Debian packaging in particular, tells me to take the time to do it the right way, otherwise be prepared for a backlash sooner or later.

Comment: @xhienne - fair point.

Answer (score 2):

> For this to work, I need to ensure `sim.local/atlas.crt` is in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`. Unfortunately there is no `/etc/ca-certificates.conf.d/` which could allow me to drop-in another file with that content.

Then add your CRT at the end of `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` manually:

```
echo sim.local/atlas.crt >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
```

Finally, call `update-ca-certificates`.

---

> Therefore, I could try:
>
> ```
> dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
> ```
>
> But this causes an interactive dialog to show up which has my certificate de-selected by default. I'd rather this was non-interactive.

Not if you set the priority of questions to "high" or above ("critical"):

```
dpkg-reconfigure -phigh ca-certificates
```

Anyway, I believe you should call `update-ca-certificates`, instead of `dpkg-reconfigure`-ing another package.